# How to detect if the author of a message was a Discord bot?

Tags: node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

The title explains my question. This question might sound stupid, but how do I detect if the author of a message was a Discord bot?

Thanks.

Comment: What if the bot uses a normal account? No it's not possible unless the bot detects itself as a bot.

Comment: Build a deep-learning algorithm to determine what is human. Then compare the input into the application to determine whether the writer is human or not. Or just target common 'botted' keywords to block - that's probably much easier.

Comment: Ask them a question only a real person would know how to answer (obviously, you have to use different questions every time).  Or, make them send messages through a captcha-type web page.

Comment: I'll clarify that a little. If the account that created the message is a Discord bot, that might clear some things up.

Comment: [Possible duplicat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46597760/how-to-check-if-discord-bot-is-the-user-entering-a-command)? (no, this is node.js, but may be related)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you want to check if a message author is a bot account you can easily do:

```
if(message.author.bot) return;
```

This will return if a user is a bot. If it isn't will keep going.
If you want to check if the message author is the logged in bot you can do:

```
if(message.author.id === client.user.id) return;
```

This is gonna return if the message author is the bot, it will keep going if its another bot.

Answer (score 1):

for those looking for an answer on how to check if it was your bot who added a reaction. In that case you can check like it like:

```html
client.on('messageReactionAdd', (messageReaction, user) => {
  if (messageReaction.me === false) {
    // This reaction was not added by the bot
  }
});
```